# Send partial view model and Update partial view with jQuery has issues

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I use partial view for small model inside other view model. so i send changes of it by grabbing model data from wrapper form and using `serializeArray()`. then return `PartialViewResult` from action and finally fill partial view div container by returned result. this is my code:

```
var modelStr = $("#[wrapperFormName]").serializeArray();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: targetUrl,
cache: false,
data: modelStr,
success: function (sucResult) {
$('#pa_Cnt').html(sucResult);
},
fail: function (result) {
alert("Fail");
}
});
```

and render partialview in view as this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("[ActionName]", "[CtrlName]", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "[wrapperFormName]", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div id="[partialcontainerName]">
        @Html.Partial("[partialViewName]", [partialViewModelName])
    </div>
}
```

One of issue is after update partial view with returned result don't work any of jQuery event handlers that bind to elements inside the partial and i know event handlers must be declare in main view and not in partial and handlers must be delegated.
Second issue is updated result has new values but some of elements in partial view show old values and i set cache of ajax to false as cache of action with `[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]`.
I'm confusing. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775170/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-clear

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is because you must re-add your event handers. I assume you are adding your event handlers within `$(document).ready` or an equivalent when the page loads. After you've refreshed your partial using $.ajax, the original elements that had event handlers no longer exist - their instances have been replaced and therefore the event handlers won't fire. You need to re-add the event handlers as part of the `success` callback after the line:

```
$('#pa_Cnt').html(sucResult);
```

Not sure about the second issue..

Comment: Thanks @David i add delegate event after this and it was work but i care about more than one delegate exist in page. and other things: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768720/jquery-ajax-partial-view-only-working-once  adeneo say about delegate events must be work and i used delegate specially by not direct selector same as this: $("[parentClassName]").on("click", '[ChildSelector]', function (e) { //Code }); I appreciate if you tell me more and it's better if companion with some sample. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. Thanks from @David for first issue. I separate internal actions of delegated events to functions that pointed with variable names and attach delegate events to them after update html of partial with returned result. this is a simple sample:

```
var sampleHandler = function() { //some code }
```

and then in ajax success:

```
success: function (sucResult) {
         $('#pa_Cnt').html(sucResult);
         $("[parentClassNameSelector]").on("click", '[childSelector]', sampleHandler);
   }
```

About second issue ModelState of MVC is Guilty. :) specially in elements that rendered by mvc helpers. So i decide to do this in controller action.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) { ModelState.Clear(); }
```

I don't know if this is good or has any other issue. For now it was solved my problem. I'm waiting for new comments and advises. Thanks so much.

Comment: See here why ModelState.Clear solves the issue : http://forums.asp.net/p/1527149/3687407.aspx